# MariaDB column compression and binlog

Tags: mariadb, compression, binlog, mysqlbinlog

I have a table with big `text` column, approx 3M per row, the table is using InnoDB storage engine. The binlog size is an issue,

I have binlog turned on and configured to format:row.

I do know about `log_bin_compress` option, but before I try it as solution and turn it on for server wide and pay for its impact, I would like to know if there is a more specific solution just for this table.

I also do know about `binlog_row_image` option `minimal`, but it seems, the application changes the column every time... so it can not spare space for me.

**Question**

If I configure column compression this text column, will it affect the size of the binlog logged event?

If this is not an option, will any kind of InnoDB compression, (either row, either page) affect size of the binlog logged event?

Comment: I guess you are using MariaDB, not MySQL, because `log_bin_compress` is not a feature in MySQL. It was developed for MariaDB.

Comment: I would be surprised if the binlog events will not be smaller if you use [column compression](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/storage-engine-independent-column-compression/) on the relevant columns. I've never tested it, but it would be silly for the MariaDB server to decompress columns before replicating / sending to the binlog.

Comment: First, some info...  Why do you even have the binlog turned on?  Replication, point-in-time-recovery, other?  Are you worried about disk space?  In what situation?  What is in `MEDIUMTEXT` column?  Maybe there is a different way to deal with it.  Is there a `FULLTEXT` index on the column?

Comment: @BillKarwin, your guess is correct about i am using MariaDB, as the very first word is the OP title is 'MariaDB' :-)

Comment: @RickJames, this is for having the opportunity of PITR.

Comment: Well, you may be stuck with only max_binelog_size and expire_logs%.  The former provides better granularity. See the size of the teeth in the saw blade when looking at the disk usage graph.)  The latter limits how far back you can do PITR.

Answer (score 1):

Binary log format is independent of storage engine.

I have not tested it, but I am pretty sure that no storage engine options will result in different binary log storage. For example if you store the table with InnoDB compression, that won't compress the value in the binary logs.

You could use gzip to compress strings or blobs in your application before storing them to the database.

If binary log size is a problem, you should also adjust the binary log retention, with [expire_logs_days](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-and-binary-log-system-variables/#expire_logs_days) or [binlog_expire_logs_seconds](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/replication-and-binary-log-system-variables/#binlog_expire_logs_seconds) (I prefer the latter if you are using MariaDB 10.6 or later).

If the binary log size is still a problem, then you should just get larger storage volumes.

Comment: many thx. I do know about log retention, however, I must archive all logs to satisfy PITR requirement. (Column compression is not storage engine feature. Although you are right in respect of InnoDB row or page compression)

Comment: You need to maintain PITR for all time? Normally you only need to keep binary logs back to the most recent full or incremental backup.

Comment: many thx for taking time to get know the actual use case. The PITR is for audit reasons, so having all historical log is mandatory. I know I can solve the issue completely outside of the rdbms, by compressing the binlog files as OS file, then decompress them if there is a need. However I would like to understand what is going on with MariaDB more deep, and having smaller binlog in MariaDB level may have other benefits, regarding disk I/O or when this binlog is used in master/slave replication.

Comment: Very well. I think you know the options by now. If you need the binary logs for archiving or auditing purposes, you still don't need to store all historical binlogs on the production database server. You can copy them to a file server or cloud storage, then let them expire on the database server.

Comment: the get larger storage is not appropriate answer in many cases, and not because the storage cost, insted because my concern usually not the storage size, but the increased I/O load. I would like to spare with my I/O bandwith in every case if there is a reasonable option

Comment: @g.pickardou - I/O bandwidth is usually controlled by better indexes or queries, not by shrinking table size.

Comment: @RickJames, all true, but this case that does not apply, no index will help to get smaller binlog... Regarding in general I/O, of course having well architected schema, with carefully chosen datatypes, PKs, having optimal indexes, including covering indexes, and also not having disaster correlated subqueries will spare I/O.

Comment: In your original question, you said "the binlog size is an issue." It's reasonable to interpret this as a concern about storage limits. It would have been helpful if you had made your original question more clear.

Comment: @g.pickardou - And is it RAM or disk?

Comment: @RickJames, disk, 200G per day. I think if, mainly coming from TEXT column INSERT statements.

Answer (score 1):

When storing large text columns, I recommend "compressing" them in the *client*, then storing into a `MEDIUMBLOB`.  This will shrink all copies of the data, include those in the binlog.  And, in *some* configurations, it will speed up things.

Comment: unfortunatelly, as dba, application implementation is not something we have effect on... Very hard and most importantly slow to make a change in app implementation, generally rejected by developers, because of fear of regression. Most importantly as dba we have to react within a way smaller time window (days), but an app implementation change requests time window in the range of months

Comment: Alas, I disagree with the corporate policy of strictly segregating DBAs and Programmers.  "Month"!  That reminds me of the "old" days.  Or Governments.

Comment: My experience this applies to any conservative enterprise. In financial industry this process is even more conservative and slower than government.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that column compression has measurable effect on the binlog size, (in case the binlog format is row)

I've created a POC which scope is limited, and does not allow generic conclusions, but results may provide some understanding.

I compared column compression vs without column compression cases on a specific TEXT column. I stored approx 5M well compressible data in each row, the data was representative sample to the production load. The result were conclusive, giving the same ratio regardless of using 100, 1000 or 10000 rows.

Column compression was set ZLIB, (and level 9 in the config file)

The InnoDB file size was approx 30-40% smaller, the binlog size was approx 40-50% smaller, to near half size.

It is interesting, that the column compression has measurable greater effect on the binlog size than the InnoDB tablespace size, I expected less effect on binlog size, if any.